# How to make a piecewise function differentiable?

Tags: derivatives

I have the following question:

Suppose $$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^2 & \text{if }x\leq 2 \\ mx+b& \text{if }x>2\end{array}\right.$$

If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then what are the values of $m$ and $b$?

How exactly would I be able to get the values to be differentiable? I know that the point at 2 has to exist and that it has to be continuous and connect to the other function to work. How exactly do I get the exact values for "m" and "b" though?

Comment: Please make your question self-contained; that is, type your question here.

Comment: @user1804933: Why do you think the answer would be unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ has to satisfy
$$
\lim_{x\to 2+}f(x)=f(2),\quad \lim_{x\to 2- }=\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\to 2+ }=\frac{f(x)-f(2)}{x-2},
$$
i.e.
$$
2m+b=4,\quad m=4 \Rightarrow m=4,b=-4.
$$